# Should the order of like/dislike buttons in Youtube Music be considered an oversight or intentional?

Tags: user-expectation

YouTube Music shows the dislike button before the like button. Personally I feel a bit disorientated every time I want to like a song since in most websites (Netflix, YouTube itself, etc.) that I use have the like button first.

**Question:** Just to play devil advocate, what could be the reason for showing the dislike button first?

My current thinking: People don't use the "like" button much. The "dislike" button are used more and actually have the purpose of both skipping songs and make sure those songs aren't recommended again.

[image: YouTube Music like/dislike button positions]

Comment: Good question! Well... if the order is based on your "current thinking" part, I believe they did a really bad job designing icons. It would be much better if the two icons were "Skip/Love(heart)" rather than "Like/Dislike"

Answer (score 3):

It is a clear example where the responsive interface applied to mobiles has clearly influenced the general interface of the application.

In a mobile device the buttons with the greatest possibility of use are located on the right, consequently it would be illogical to change the buttons position in desktop interfaces.

[image]

Comment: I see the reason for putting frequently-used buttons on the right is most people are right-handed. However, I don't look at it this way... for left-handed, the frequent-use-area is flipped and is on the left. I want to look at the order based on the language context: whether it's RTL or LTR.